# In Syncfusion Docking Manager is it possible to set TargetNameInDockedMode with respect to 2 targetnames?

Tags: wpf, syncfusion

I am working on a WPF Project using sync fusion and caliburn micro. I need to set a new dock(say dock 3) right side of another dock(say dock 1) and below another dock say( dock 2).

Comment: Show an example of what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot set two TargetNames in TargetNameInDockedMode for a single child of DockingManager. You can achieve your requirement by placing the child right to one(Dock1) and below another(Dock2) without using two target names. Use the below snippet,

```
  <syncfusion:DockingManager x:Name="dockingmanager" DockFill="True">
        <ContentControl x:Name="dock1" syncfusion:DockingManager.Header="Dock1"/>
        <ContentControl x:Name="dock2" syncfusion:DockingManager.Header="Dock2" syncfusion:DockingManager.SideInDockedMode="Right"/>
        <ContentControl x:Name="dock3" syncfusion:DockingManager.Header="Dock3" syncfusion:DockingManager.SideInDockedMode="Bottom" syncfusion:DockingManager.TargetNameInDockedMode="dock2"/>
    </syncfusion:DockingManager>
```

If this doesn't meet your requirement, share more information like, how you want to dock the child(screenshot would be helpful) and what is the specific need for two TargetNames.

Regards,
Durga S.